# Is it possible to use pip to install the latest tag?

Tags: python, pip

One can use pip to install a specific tag:

```
pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.com/{usr}/{repo}.git@{tag}#egg={egg}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to make it point to the latest release (which would be `releases/latest`), and not just to the HEAD of master. Is it at all possible?

One constraint, it has to use ssh.

Comment: Hmh, Why don't you simply specify the exact commit id of the tag?

Comment: @cel commits don't have any meaning attached to them, while I can tell someone to install version 1.0.3 or something.
I don't want to have to update my README every time I publish a release, and I want my users to use the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python packages here is one way to do this:

setup.py

```
import setuptools
import urllib.request


deps = [
    {
        'name': 'gunicorn',
        'url': 'github.com/benoitc/gunicorn',
    },
]

for i in range(len(deps)):
    tag_url = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://{deps[i]['url']}/releases/latest").geturl()
    latest_tag = tag_url.split('/')[-1]
    deps[i] = f"{deps[i]['name']} @ git+ssh://{deps[i]['url']}@{latest_tag}"

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=deps,
)
```

And then install the package locally

```
python -m pip install .
```

Comment: Cool solution! Question: Why not just `tag_url.split('/')[-1]` instead of `tag_url.split('/')[::-1][0]`

Comment: @Icnittl good catch